# How to tokenize a SQL Server column for use in frequency distribution in SSAS

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012, statistics, ssas

I have a field in my table called `Description` . Here is an examples of a few records:

```
+-----------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
| RecordKey | RecordType | Price |                                                                                                                                                 Description                                                                                                                                                 | RecordNumber | DiscsinSet | Country | Company | DigitalAnalogCode |     Genre     |     UPC     | datecreated |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
|    100488 | CD         | 5.99  | Korngold, Honegger, Verdi, Wagner, Puccini, Leoncavallo, Giordano: Opera Arias + 'I Know Where I'm Going'. (Ellen Faull, soprano. Taken from the Sylvan Levin Opera Concert Broadcasts of 1951 & 1952. Total time: 65'47')                                                                                  | VAIA 1173    |          1 | AMERICA | VAI     | M                 | Songs & Arias | 89948117322 | 42:38.4     |
|    100503 | CD         | 11.98 | Puccini, Madama Butterfly. (Kirsten, Barioni, Nadell et al. New Orleans Opera/ Cellini. Rec.3/60)                                                                                                                                                                                                           | VAIA 1054-2  |          2 | AMERICA | VAI     | A                 | Opera         | 89948105428 | 42:38.4     |
|    100516 | MV         | 8.99  | Brahms, 8 Gypsy Songs. Schumann, 2 Short Gypsy Songs. Liszt, The 3 Gypsies. Verdi, The Gypsy Woman. J.Strauss, 'Gypsy Baron'- Song of Sapphi + Other Gypsy Songs by Balakirev, Varlamov, Tchaikovsky, Verstovskij, Dvorak & Lehar. (Ljuba Kazarnovskaya, soprano w.Mark Morash, piano. Rec.Moscow, 2/19/98) | 69503        |          1 | AMERICA | VAI     | S                 | NULL          | 89948695035 | 42:38.4     |
+-----------+------------+-------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+--------------+------------+---------+---------+-------------------+---------------+-------------+-------------+
```

Apologies, if it is difficult to read, but the `description` field has a lot of text.

I would like to create a frequency distribution of every word in this field.

**The output I would like would look something like this:**

```
+-----------+-------+
|   word    | count |
+-----------+-------+
| Beethoven |   344 |
| Strauss   | 34533 |
| Piano     |     3 |
| Webber    |    34 |
+-----------+-------+
```

**If it makes more sense, could you point me in the right direction on how this can be achieved with SSAS?**

Answer (score 1):

If you have a separate list of valid words, you can just do:

```
select w.word, count(*)
from mytable t join
     words w
     on ', ' + w.word + ', ' like '%, ' + t.description + ', %'
group by w.word;
```

If you don't, then look around the web for a `split()` function.  You can then use `cross apply` for something like:

```
select w.value, count(*)
from mytable t cross apply
     (select *
      from split(t.description, ', ')
     ) w
group by w.value;
```

If you have control over the data structure, then naughty, naughty.  SQL has this wonderful data structure for storing lists.  It is called a table.  It is not called a string.  You should be using a junction table -- if you have control.  One doesn't always have control over such issues, though.

Comment: i suppose i will have to find a more fancy split function since have multiple delimitters like ,;:-_ etc

Comment: in fact, i would like the delimitter to be every character except a-z, A-Z, and 0 - 9

Comment: @Yuck . . . There are many versions of the `split()` function around.  You should easily be able to adapt one for the delimiters you want.